# Mean of a specific part of the matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix

I must calculate the mean in this specific part of the matrix, that was generated with random numbers, my work so far:

```
import random as rd
import numpy as np

matriz= np.zeros([12, 12])

for i in range(0,12):
    for j in range(0,12):
        matriz[i,j]=rd.randint(0,10)
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like you've *tried* anything yet. What ahve you tried, and what, specifically, is holding you up? Errors? (if so, post the trace & code). Output not matching what you expect? (If so, show example data and output, etc.)

Comment: i don't know exactly how to calculate the mean of this part only, thats what holding me up

Comment: How this part is specified? give us an example.

Comment: well could you try brute force iteration, appending each of the vlaues to a list object, and then doing the avg from that list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is trying to fit an algorithm. There's clearly a structure to the "marked" section of your matrix, so your problem is in trying to see/identify this structure, in order to fit it.

What I see is a pattern: starting with row 0, you're taking columns from 1 to n-1, then in row 1 you're taking columns 2 to n-2, etc.  So basically, you're summing the coordinates for each row in `range(rowIndex+1, len(columns)-(rowIndex+1))`

There may be some more elegant ways to achieve this, but I think this will work:

```
import random as rd
import numpy as np

l, w = 12, 12   # matrix has dimensions l=12, w=12
matriz= np.zeros([l, w])

for i in range(l):
    for j in range(w):
        matriz[i,j]=rd.randint(0,10) 

vals = []

for i in range(int(l/2)):     # iterate through rows 0 to 4
    for j in range(i+1, w-(i+1)):
        vals.append(matrix[i,j])

# get the mean:
print 'mean is {}'.format(sum(vals)/len(vals))
```

Note this probably doesn't work for a non-square matrix.